# How to fix this error on android studio? Error while install APK on android studio 3.2.1

Tags: android-studio, android-install-apk

I am building an app on our device and has an error of

> com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
>   Error while Installing APK

Can you help me about this?

I tried `sudo adb kill server` & `sudo adb start-server` on terminal but it's failing again

I run this

```
sudo adb kill-server & sudo adb start-server
```

Output:

```
[2] 12133
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
[1]   Done                    sudo adb kill-server
[2]+  Done                    sudo adb kill-server
```

I expected that after I run the `sudo adb start-server`, the app will run. But it failed

Comment: the error says it all "Please check the confirmation dialog on your device", when connecting your device to your machine laptop or pc, you should allow the machine to connect and usb debugging must be enabled

Comment: Allow USB Debugging will appear in your device, always enabled it when your device connected to the pc.

Comment: The device has adb, so if I run the "sudo adb start-server" it will enable the debugging.

Comment: Can you help me about this? I can't start my application that I make, there always an error about this,

"$ adb push /home/macky/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.macky.myapplication
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
Error while Installing APK"